# Maximum preserved under monotonic mapping

Tags: maxima-minima, monotone-functions

For some strictly non-negative function $f\,\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+$, and a monotonically increasing function $g\,\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+$, is there a name (theorem or lemma name?) to the result
$$
\arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x) = \arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} g(f(x)).
$$

It seems obvious enough, so I am sure it must go by a more formal name. (I can consider smaller subsets of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: The stated equality is obvious if $g$ is strictly increasing and false otherwise. There is no name for it.

Comment: Suggestion: call it Lemma of Fred.

Comment: I know it's obvious. For example so is the intermediate value theorem, but the latter does have a name.